# How to make packager package "Static Image Resources" in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

the codes:

**img.js**

```
module.exports = {
    back: require('./back.png'),
    write: require('./write.png'),
    talk: require('./talk.png')
};
```

**Toolbar.js**

```
let img = require('../../img/img');
// ...
<ToolbarAndroid navIcon={img.back} />
```

**the file paths**

```
|- widget/Toolbar/Toolbar.js
|- img/
    |-img.js
    |-back.png
    |-back@2x.png 
    |-back@3x.png
    |-talk.png
    |-talk@2x.png
    |-talk@3x.png
    |-write.png
    |-write@2x.png
    |-write@3x.png
```

The image working well in my genymotion, but did not visible in my mobile.
So, how does the packager packages "Static Image Resources"? or am I missed some document?

Comment: Which version are you using? I had trouble packaging my assets after upgrading RN, but when I created a fresh project, it worked great

Answer (score 1):

In DEV mode packager won't bundle images as a part of your app, instead it will replace `require` statements with URLs to the packager server.

You are most likely not seeing images on your device because you don't have access to the packager server from your device. If you're on android 5.0+ and connected with USB you can run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`. See [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html) link for more options depending on the setup you have